# Is the WhatsApp backup feature activated by default?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

In WhatsApp for Android, are the chat backup features activated by default? If so, how is the backup interval by default? Daily, weekly or monthly? Are the chat backups being stored on the phone or on Google drive?

Comment: Read the WhatsApp FAQ?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the default. It just explains how to do a back up etc. which I do know already. I just want to know how the default is on android phones.

Answer (score 1):

By default, WhatsApp would make a local backup daily (stored in the phone), but if you wish there is an option to also backup to Google Drive after the local backup finishes.

I looked in my WhatsApp settings, it seems the Google Drive backup was set to never (it was Off), looked in my friend's WhatsApp and same thing (it was Off as well), so I guess the Google Drive Backup is not turned on by default, you need to turn it on manually.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp creates the backup on local devices daily at 2 AM. You can not change this time.

Although WhatsApp has also provided to create cloud backup on Google Drive with backup frequency daily/weekly/monthly. To create a backup, you can go to
Menu > Settings > Chats > Chat backup.